# Publishing tif with elevation data to geoserver

Tags: qgis, geoserver, gdal

I Have been trying to publish a DEM built from SRTM data (both a vrt of the .hgt files and a GeoTiff converted from the vrt).
I Keep getting `Cannot enable, no attribute of type Number found` on both elevation and time dimensions no matter what data type i save them in.
Is there a a specific data type which GeoServer will recognize as **Number**?
If so what is the conversion method that will work on best on the tif file with GDAL or QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time and elevation dimensions are used for datasets that have various features that were created at different times and/or occured at different elevations, for example an earthquake dataset might have depth (negative elevation) and timestamp and so could have both a TIME and ELEVATION dimension set. Since you have a single raster that represents elevation rather than a set of rasters showing say temperature at different elevations there is no need for you to set the ELEVATION attribute.

You will simply need to add a style to [colourize](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html) your raster and possibly a layer of [contours](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#contour-extraction).

Comment: Thank you. that was unclear. I was thinking of using specific dimensions when calling the dataset from my client side.